# Disable auto play in YouTube embeded code

Tags: html, youtube, autoplay

How to disable auto play option in YouTube embedded code.
my Video embedded code is like below and i have checked the ?autoplay=0 method. but it not working.

this is the YouTube code:

```html
<iframe width="711" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?rel=0?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

i have checked like below:

```html
<iframe width="1400" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?autoplay=0&rel=0&ecver=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To disable autoplay, just put `&autoplay=0` after the video ID. see the below line:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/blahblah&autoplay=0"
```

Comment: yes, I had put &autoplay=0 at the end of the video ID. but it's not affected. please check the above embedded code.

Comment: seems like you have written **?autoplay=0** try changing it to **&autoplay=0**

Comment: its not working. if placing this not showing the video

Comment: you have to use the old embed video for the parameter to work

Comment: try your original code in mozilla and see if it is working

Answer (score 0):

try with this hope it will helps you.

```
<object width="425" height="350">
<param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?autoplay=0"></param>
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E5ln4uR4TwQ?autoplay=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for an answer and found that adding `?rel=0` to the end of the link seems to work

Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/code for video?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```